# This webpage is not available

Tags: azure, timeout

I am newbie in Azure development ,I am migrating an existing asp.net application to be hosted as cloud service ,everything works just fine locally (on dev. AppFabric) but when I publish it on cloud and after I try to singin on my signin.aspx page it keeps giving me "This webpage is not available" error .
after that refreshing the page gives me "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable." error
my signin page does a lot of stuff (calling db procedure ,setting user session) before redirecting to default page [I am using the free azure trial account]

what may cause the problem ,how can I debug ,why everything works fine on the emulator ?

Comment: Can you try tracing the request through Fiddler and see what's the HTTP status message you are getting? Are you getting 404, 400, 500 or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the event Viewer I found that the problem was in "Debugger.Break ();" inside a class it seems like that line just freaks the runtime out and causes it to lose control and recycle the Application Pool and stopping the service !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a remote desktop connection to your web role instance and look at the Event Log for IIS.  You will want this for development and testing independent of your current issue.

Links:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/remote-desktop/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg443832.aspx